# How to include shieldui in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shieldui

I'm new to `shieldui` js and asp.net mvc and I'm doing some examples for a train. I have no problem including the js in a html file but I'm struggling to include it in asp.net mvc. Lets say i have jquery and shield ui in Scripts folder. I did reference `Shield.Mvc.UI` but I still cant access them via `@(Html.XXXX)`.

Lets say i want to create `ShieldCalendar` using `View.cshtml`. The example is:

```
<div class="container">
@(Html.ShieldCalendar()
    .Name("calendar")
    .HtmlAttribute("class", "calendar")
    .Min(new DateTime(2009, 2, 23))
    .Max(new DateTime(2039, 3, 1))
    .Value(DateTime.Now)
    .Footer(fb => fb.Enabled(true).FooterTemlpate("{0:dd.MM.yy}")))
```

I'm a beginner and I may miss something fundamental for asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Later findings: it looks like some time ago there weren't html helper extension methods for that. Are you sure you have something like that?

Question reference: [shield ui chart: generate series dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031573/shield-ui-chart-generate-series-dynamically) (where op is saying that he wrote a custom html helper for .net mvc)

Html helpers reference: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/html-helpers

Are you sure you have html helpers in `Shield.Web.UI` namespace? (see this question too: [Referencing the Shield UI ASP.NET MVC javascript modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405102/referencing-the-shield-ui-asp-net-mvc-javascript-modules))

**1st approach**

You can create a bundle with those two javascript files for now.

Open the `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs`, there you will have a `RegisterBundles` method where you can create a bundle with those two files.

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
 {
     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryand")
              .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"))
              .Include("~/Scripts/shieldui.js"); 
              // i don't know exactly the name of the library

 }
```

And in your `Global.asax.cs`, you need to register this bundle:

In Application_Start method, add the following line:

```
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Then in your `_Layout` or your more specific view, you'll have to add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

More about this approach here: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

And here: 
[How do I add BundleConfig.cs to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668280/how-do-i-add-bundleconfig-cs-to-my-project) (probably this question is very useful)

**2nd approach**

Use something like RequireJs for .NET, which will bring some features to your application, but will also add some complexity.

See my answer for the question below:

[RequireJS - ASP.NET MVC Bundle Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942322/requirejs-asp-net-mvc-bundle-script/30641224#30641224)

About this part of your problem:

> but I still cant access them via @(Html.XXXX).

Maybe your intellisense is broken, you can give it a try after you add the script to the page/layout and after you make sure that you have

```
@using Shield.Web.UI
```

for your page/layout.

Comment: If you have any more questions, please reply to this thread. Maybe it's better to come back with some exceptions if you're facing some.